# Android pause/resume AsynTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a UI thread(MainActivity) calling an AsynTask object(DownloadManager), which, in turn calls 3 threads (DownloaderThread).

How do I pause/resume the 3 DownloaderThreads without pausing the AsynTask or the UI thread?

Following is the code I have currently implemented for the pause functionality, but when the Pause button is clicked, the app crashes with the dialog: "app has stopped". Code:

DownloadManager (AsynTask):

```
public void onPause() {
    try{
        t0.wait();
        t1.wait();
        t2.wait();
        this.wait();
    }catch (InterruptedException ex){

    }
}
```

DownloaderThread (implements Runnable and is passed to a Thread instance in DownloadManager:

```
public class DownloaderThread implements Runnable {
    private Object mPauseLock;
    private Boolean mPaused;
    private Boolean mFinished;
public void run(){
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    try{
        while(!mFinished){
            //do something
            synchronized (mPauseLock){
                while (mPaused){
                    try{
                        mPauseLock.wait();
                    }catch (InterruptedException e){

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onPause(){
    synchronized (mPauseLock){
        mPaused = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have learnt that its not possible to call the onPause method of the DownloaderThread without using some kind of thread to runnable object mapping. if someone can guide on how to implement that, that would be great..

Answer (score 0):

You can't really pause an AsyncTask once it started. You can, however, store the progress when activity is paused/destroyed and start from the progress once you are back to the original Activity. But I recommend the best way to complete task for your scenario is to use [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).